# How to ensure that a stored function always returns TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, coalesce, postgresql-9.5

With the following stored function I would like to validate user data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user(
        in_social integer,
        in_sid varchar(255),
        in_auth varchar(32))
        RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
        SELECT MD5('secret word' || in_social || in_sid) = in_auth;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

I am going to call it while looping through a JSON array of objects in another stored functions - and will `RAISE EXCEPTION` if it returns `FALSE` for any of the JSON objects (and thus rollback the whole transaction).

Instead of dumping here the source code of my 2nd stored function, I have prepared 3 simple test functions below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1() RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
        IF NOT check_user(42, 'user1', '56db1046fa7b664c9b3d05bf7413552a') THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'invalid user';
        ELSE
                RAISE NOTICE 'valid user';
        END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 1st function works as expected and prints `valid user`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2() RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
        IF NOT check_user(42, 'user2', '56db1046fa7b664c9b3d05bf7413552a') THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'invalid user';
        ELSE
                RAISE NOTICE 'valid user';
        END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 2nd function works as expected and prints `invalid user`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test3() RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
        IF NOT check_user(42, 'user1', NULL) THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'invalid user';
        ELSE
                RAISE NOTICE 'valid user';
        END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 3rd function **does not work as expected** and prints `valid user`.

This happens because `check_user()` returns `NULL` instead of a boolean value.

`COALESCE` could be wrapped around the `check_user()` call in the `IF`-statement... but is there maybe a nicer way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [is [not] distinct from](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)

```
select md5('secret word' || in_social || in_sid) is not distinct from in_auth;
```

But notice that if both sides evaluate to `null` the comparison will return `true`:

> For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM is the same as the <> operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, IS NOT DISTINCT FROM is identical to = for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null. Thus, these constructs effectively act as though null were a normal data value, rather than "unknown".

Even simpler is to just declare the function [`strict`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) and compare the returned value with `is not true`:

```
if check_user(42, 'user1', null) is not true then raise notice 'invalid user';
```

> STRICT indicates that the function always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

This has the added benefit of avoiding any cost of executing the function.

Comment: In the 2nd statement (for the `STRICT` function) is it mandatory to use `is not true` part? Can't I just use `if NOT check_user(42, 'user1', null) then raise notice 'invalid user'; end if;` ? Thank you

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: `expression is not true` will return true for both `false` and `null` while `not expression` will only return `true` for `false` not for `null` which is your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the coalesce inside the check_user() function, so it always returns true or false.

```
    SELECT MD5('secret word' || in_social || in_sid) = coalesce(in_auth,'');
```

Or even the option below in case the other values could also be NULL :

```
    SELECT MD5('secret word' || coalesce(in_social,-1)::varchar || coalesce(in_sid,'')) = coalesce(in_auth,'');
```

being there "-1" a value that will never be assigned to in_social

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will probably use, because the function is security related and as thus I don't want having to remember any edge cases (like mandatory use of `IF check_user(...) IS NOT TRUE` when declaring it as `STRICT`) when using it in future -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user(
        in_social integer, 
        in_sid varchar(255), 
        in_auth varchar(32))
        RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN in_social IS NULL THEN FALSE
                WHEN in_sid    IS NULL THEN FALSE
                WHEN in_auth   IS NULL THEN FALSE
                ELSE (MD5('secret word' || in_social || in_sid) = in_auth)
        END;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```